# iterate in the method until user provides input in alphabets only

Tags: c#

I am showing a part of my input code in this problem statement. I want to get the input in only alphabets from the user. Here I want to iterate through this method until the user provide input in alphabets. getInput is the method in my class.

```
public string getInput() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name. If you want to send the parcel: ");
    this.NameOfSender = Console.ReadLine();
    return NameOfSender;
}
```

Here I want that If user enter wrong input this code should print message "Wrong Input. Please enter valid name." and then goto start of the method again. Please help me how to do that.

Comment: Create a boolean variable and set it to false.  Loop while the variables is false.  If the input is valid, set it to true.

Comment: Look up a RegEx for alphanumeric entries. Match the ReadLine against the Regex. If it passes, write "thank you." If not, write "Must be alpha" and then call getInput again

Comment: @DStanley Please can you provide me a bit of code for this. Either i need to use while loop? or something else. Please if you may provide me the code I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this (*Linq* `All`); do not forget check for an *empty input* (if user just pressed enter):

```
public string getInput() {
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name. If you want to send the parcel: ");

  while (true) {
    NameOfSender = Console.ReadLine();

    // if name is 
    //   1. Not empty
    //   2. Contains letters only
    // then return it; otherwise keep asking 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameOfSender) && 
         NameOfSender.All(c => char.IsLetter(c))) 
      return NameOfSender;

    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input. Enter name again");
  } 
}
```

**Edit**: in case you allow *spaces* between letters (e.g *John Smith*) you can use *regular expresion* in the `if`:

```
    ...
    if (Regex.IsMatch(NameOfSender, @"^\p{L}+( \p{L}+)*$")) 
      return NameOfSender;
    ...
```

Comment: bro thanks it worked for me but I want one more edit in this. First time it should ask "please enter your name. If you want to send the parcel" but if the user inputs wrong input that it should say "Wrong input. Enter name again". I will mark this as my answer after this.

Comment: one problem in this code is that it is not letting me to add space in the name or address in below part of the question. How to cope with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
//This regex pattern will accept alphabet only, no numbers or special chars like blank spaces
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]"); 

do{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name. If you want to send the parcel: ");
    this.NameOfSender = Console.ReadLine();
    boolean isOnlyAlpha = p.matcher(this.NameOfSender).matches();
}while(!isOnlyAlpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate the users input, something like:

```
if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[\w\s]+")) 
{
    ...
```

Should do the trick

Learn about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

edit: Of course users can have hyphens in their name, so that regex will not actually capture all valid names.

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare this variable in your class
public string Name = null;

//change the return type to void
public void getInput(){
    string CheckString = null;
    while (Name.IsNullOrEmpty()){
        bool IsValid = true;
        checkString = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (char c in CheckString.ToCharArray()){
            if (!Char.IsLetter(c)){
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input!");
                IsValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (IsValid){
            Name = CheckString;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop will run until the text the user has given only contains letters and when it finds this condition to be true it will set the variable Name to the text the user has given.